# Python re.search regex using or condition

Tags: python, regex

Hi Friends I'm trying to include "or |" condition in search pattern using re.search. Can someone help me how to achieve or condition as I'm not getting match.
Below code works

```
>>> pattern = re.escape('apple.fruit[0]')
>>> sig = 'apple.fruit[0]'
>>> if re.search(pattern, sig):
...    print("matched")
...
matched 
>>> pattern = re.escape('apple.fruit[0] or vegi[0]')
>>> if re.search(pattern, sig):
...    print("matched")
...
>>>
```

I want to match above string  "apple." followed by fruit[0] or vegi[0]

Comment: I believe `or` in regexes are represented by `|`, not `or`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex or should be achieved through `|` operator and we don't inculde this inside `re.escape`. If you do so, then it would loose it's special meaning.

```
pattern = re.escape('apple.fruit[0]')+ '|' + re.escape('vegi[0]')
```

or

```
pattern = r'apple\.fruit\[0\]|vegi\[0\]'
```